# Is it possible to run a tar command in directory A which creates a tar archive in directory B out of a file in directory C?

Tags: shell, tar

Here's what I'm starting with:

```
ls "$A"
<current_directory>
ls "$B"
<nothing>
ls "$C"
my_file
```

Here's what I want to end up with:

```
tar -vczf <magic> "${B}/my_archive.tar.gz" "${C}/my_file"
ls "$B"
my_archive.tar.gz # contains my_file at root of archive (no directory)
pwd
<still in A>
```

I've read through the tar man page several times now.  My only conclusion is that it would be easier to read if the flags were listed alphabetically instead of grouped by function.  ;-|  I feel like this problem should be solvable with some incantation involving the -C flag, but that only seems to help with obtaining the file in C.  I've also been trying to overcome tar's limitations with various iterations of:

```
pushd "$B"
tar -vczf <magic> "my_archive.tar.gz" "${C}/my_file"
popd
```

A last resort approach would be:

```
pushd "$C"
tar -vczf my_archive.tar.gz my_file
mv my_archive.tar.gz "$B"
popd
```

This is the only thing that's worked so far.  4 commands though!?  There has to be a better way.

[Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1168/).

Comment: Concerning the XKCD: `tar --help` would need less than 10s and is a completly valid tar command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$A`, `$B` and `$C` are absolute paths, something along the lines of

```
tar -C "$C" -czf "$B/my_archive.tar.gz" "my_file"
```

should work: the `-C` parameter translates to *"Change to DIR before performing any operations.  This option is order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow."*

You would need `$(realpath $A)` and friends to fix relative paths.

Comment: Trying this out now.  I believe that should be -czf though since I'm creating the archive, right?

Comment: Good catch! `c` and `x` are side-by-side on the keyboard ...

Comment: I'd been trying -C after the other flags, which wasn't working.  This does!